# Hamachi failing to install/start on debian 8 server

Tags: debian, lsb

i am trying to set up a headless minecraft server using debian.
So far everything is working save for hamachi (portforwarding is coming later).
I installed the .deb file from https://secure.logmein.com/labs and i get this on install:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/lsb/remove_initd", line 46, in <module>
    headers = initdutils.scan_initfile(initfile)
File "/usr/lib/lsb/initdutils.py", line 79, in scan_initfile
    inheaders = RFC822Parser(strob=headerlines)
File "/usr/lib/lsb/initdutils.py", line 24, in __init__
    fileob = StringIO(strob)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

however the install completes "successfully". If i type `hamachi` i get no feedback for 20s, then

```
Hamachi does not seem to be running.
Run '/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start' to start daemon.
```

starting the service reports no errors, but the above happens again. `hamachi --help` reports proper output, but any `hamachi [command]` does not work

Having a look at syslog i see:

```
Nov 19 11:53:03 Server avahi-daemon[15702]: Registering new address record for 25.29.60.87 on ham0.IPv4.
Nov 19 11:53:03 Server avahi-daemon[15702]: Withdrawing address record for 25.29.60.87 on ham0.
Nov 19 11:53:03 Server avahi-daemon[15702]: Withdrawing workstation service for ham0.
Nov 19 11:53:03 Server avahi-daemon[15702]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface ham0.IPv4 with address 25.29.60.87.
Nov 19 11:53:03 Server avahi-daemon[15702]: IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP failed: No such device
```

Last thing: when i first installed it, `hamachi` returned something like the expected output. I am vague since this was over 2000 lines of shell ago.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

1. In terminal, please type: `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`
2. Then, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Type in your password (if prompted) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>↓</kbd> until you reach the bottom of the file (when <kbd>↓</kbd> doesn't do anything anymore)
5. Add the line `net.ipv6.conf.ham0.disable_ipv6 = 0` to the bottom of the file
6. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
7. Press <kbd>Y</kbd>
8. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
9. Type `sudo reboot` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If this doesn't fix the issue, try this:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install lsb -y` in terminal
2. Type in your password (if prompted) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Reinstall logmein-hamachi

   - If you installed hamachi with a deb file, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure logmein-hamachi` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - If you installed hamachi through other means, please check elsewhere for this step
4. Run `sudo reboot` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: the ipv6 thing worked for me - i had disabled it on all interfaces (even the ones that are created later like this one) so hamachi was having trouble starting up (you can check that with `hamachid debug` )